# How to create a heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Here's is an example of dataset:

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(19327, 19358, 19389, 19417, 
19448, 12053), class = "Date"), branques = c("index", "index", 
"index", "index", "index", "Indústries extractives"), values = c(-1.1, 
4, -1.6, 1.1, -6.5, 20)), row.names = c(252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
256L, 269L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

I want to create a heatmap; so in the x axis there should be the `time`from January 2022 and in the y axis there should be `branques` (alphabetically ordered). It should be filled with `values`, so for each `branques`the more negative its number is the more red it should be, and when it's positive it should be green.

It should look something like:

[image]

So far, I've tried:

```
ggplot(varIPI_branques_CAT_long, aes(x = time, y = branques, fill=values)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), breaks = "2 months", labels=date_format("%b %y"),
               limits = c(as.Date("2022/01/01"), NA)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs( x = "% de variació interanual", 
        y = " ") +
  # Override default fill 
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "seq",
                       palette = "Reds",
                       limits = c(min(varIPI_branques_CAT_long$values), max(varIPI_branques_CAT_long$values)),
                       direction = 1,
                       na.value = "#FBF2F0")
```

I get this:

[image]

But, how can I limit the sample of this map so it only uses values from January 2022 onwards? And also, there should be no space in between months.

Comment: you should filter your dataset before plotting rather than using the axis limits. for example using `dplyr` you could use `varIPI_branques_CAT_long <- varIPI_branques_CAT_long %>% filter(time >= as.Date("2022-01-01"))`, that should fix your color scale

Comment: Ok thanks! And how can I delete spaces in between columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) For a diverging palette, take `type = 'div'` and choose a diverging palette.  I would strongly recommend against red/green as it is unfriendly to those who have red/green colorblindness.  red/blue might be a better choice.

If you really do want red/green, you want to use `scale_fill_gradient2`, which is very customizable.

(2) I initially misread the problem on this.  I believe the issue is caused by the fact that the number of days in each month changes (the gap is occurring for months with more than 30 days).  Thus, it's going to require some trickery (and pre-filtering  as suggested by brettjausn) to fix.

```
library(ggplot)
library(scales)
library(tidyverse) # specifically requires dplyr (mutate) and forcats (fct_reorder)

df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(19327, 19358, 19389, 19417, 
                                        19448, 12053), class = "Date"), branques = c("index", "index", 
                                                                                     "index", "index", "index", "Indústries extractives"), values = c(-1.1, 
                                                                                                                                                      4, -1.6, 1.1, -6.5, 20)), row.names = c(252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              256L, 269L), class = "data.frame")


df |>
  mutate(
    date_char = format(time, "%b %y") |>
      factor() |>
      fct_reorder(time),
  ) |>
  mutate(
    scaled_value = scale(values),
    .by = branques
  ) |>
  filter(
    time >= as.Date("2022-01-01")
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = date_char, y = branques, fill=scaled_value)) +
  geom_tile()+  # Make tile plot
  scale_x_discrete(
    expand=c(0,0),
    # date_breaks = "1 months", labels=date_format("%b%y"),
    # limits = c(as.Date("2023/01/01"), NA)) +
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)
  ) +
  labs( x = "% de variació interanual", 
        y = " ") +
  # Override default fill 
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = 'red',
    mid = "white",
    high = 'green',
    midpoint = 0, # default, switch if a different value is wanted
   limits = range(df$values)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks!! And how can I delete the space between columns?

Comment: That should have been addressed by the "date_char" variable as your x-axis.

Comment: One thing that is incorrect is that the colour range should be specific to each `branques`. Say there's no "overall" green number and same with red. Is there any way to make this colour range specific?

Comment: You need to scale the data (separately for each `branques`) for that.  See edits in the answer